# Visual Studio, CMake and Toolchain Files

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

before I explain my current problem with Visual Studio in combination with CMake, I try to explain what I want to accomplish as there might be a better solution.

At our company we have a huge code base mainly written in C for QNX. For development we are using the standard IDE QNX momentics. As this is based on a quite old eclipse version ... the whole IDE sucks.

I'm currently evaluating to use Visual Studio as a replacement. With a really simple HelloWorld-programm I was able to build and debug the project from within VS using CMake and a CMakeSettings.json.

As our code base is basically organized in a tree-like structure, I've created a typical hierarchy of CMakeLists.txt which allows me to build single/multiple projects.
As QNX delivers its own compiler I've created a toolchain file, this is running fine so far, the required toolchain is invoked once a build is triggered via cmake.

Now for the part that I'm struggling with:
How to use this CMake setup in order to develop/debug code from VS?

I had two ideas in mind which don't really work or I'm doing something wrong.

1. Use the CMake generator for VS 2019 and generate a complete solution. Problem: The toolchain file is not "used" as all projects will be setup with the internal VS compilers. Is there any way to get this working? I thought calling *cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$FILE* would do the job. Additionally: how would I incorporate the debugger configuration? With this solution the CMakeSettings.json seems to be ignored as VS solutions are used.
2. Use File->Open->CMake to open the root project. Shouldn't this show all "contained" projects which also include a CMakeLists.txt as projects? I can only see the folder tree in the Solution Explorer. Build a single project from the solution explorer is also not possible ... there is simply no option.

Anyone with experience on this topic?

Comment: *Shouldn't this show all "contained" projects which also include a CMakeLists.txt as projects?* Yes it should, but you need to switch the view from folder view to the "CMake targets view". Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't do that automatically. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-targets-view-single-file-compilation-and-cache-generation-settings/ explains how to switch between the different views. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @Corristo No, in the target view is only the top-level project displayed. The CMakeLists.txt of this "project" contains only add_subdirectory() commands.

Comment: I'm used to opening cmake projects via VS using `cmake --open <your build directory goes here>` or simply by double clicking the solution I generate using powershell (or some other command line). This results in `CMakeLists.txt` files being displayed in the solution explorer, but not necessarily all of them: every target also contains the `CMakeLists.txt` file that contains the command creating this target, which means those files could be listed multiple times or not at all e.g. in case you've got `CMakeLists.txt` files only containing `add_subdirectory` commands.

Comment: As for the debugging: You could check, if the visual studio specific properties work for you (those starting with `VS_`, especially `VS_DEBUGGER_...`): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html

Comment: @Fabian I cannot generate a solution as it will not use the toolchain file. Why are the projects which are defined via add_subdirectory() not shown? If that is not possible this seems senseless to me

Answer (score -1):

Minor comment please limit questions to 1 question in the future. Multiple questions clutters questions and makes search results worse.

============================================================

I'll answer question #1 this part of question number 1.

"Use the CMake generator for VS 2019 and generate a complete solution. Problem: The toolchain file is not "used" as all projects will be setup with the internal VS compilers. Is there any way to get this working? I thought calling cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$FILE would do the job."

Instead of using Visual Studio as your generator try using "Ninja" instead. Ninja will work if your toolchain code is correct. Toolchains and visual studio are complicated to say the least. If you wanna go down that rabbit hole I can help but that's a separate question

Basically try switching to Ninja instead of Visual Studio as your generator for CMakeSettings.json. Ninja is very easy to write toolchains for.

======================================================================

"Additionally: how would I incorporate the debugger configuration?"

The MSDN articles are actually quite good. I figured it out this week. In my opinion the debugger configurations are more powerful with the CMake approach than vanilla visual studio.

Configure CMake debugging sessions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configure-cmake-debugging-sessions?view=msvc-160

"Tutorial: Debug a CMake project on a remote Windows machine"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-remote-debugging?view=msvc-160

Trust me once it clicks you'll love it.

Comment: I don't get what switching to Ninja has to do with the CMakeSettings.json? Also: as I wrote in the comments in my question the project navigation in the solution manager is not really working when opening the root CMakeLists.txt compared to the solution approach when using the VS generator